# Update another Column with after insert trigger

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables:

`PolicyCoverage (POLICYCOVERAGEID,CoverageID,POLICYID,POLICYCOVERENROLLDATE)`

`Coverage(CoverageID,COVERAGECODE,COVERAGEMONTHLYRATE)`

`Policy(POLICYID,POLICYENROLLMENT_DATE,POLICYEFFECTIVE_START_DATE,POLICYMONTHLYPREMIUM)`

The issue i'm facing is in the creation of an the after Insert trigger.When a `coverageID` is inserted in table `PolicyCoverage` it should populate table `Policy` with `POLICYMONTHLYPREMIUM`.

I can't seem to be able to Read the coverageID that is inserted and convert it to a query to fetch the *premium* value  in order to update MonthlyPremium on Coverage.

My code so far the following:

```
 create trigger popmonthlyprem
after insert on policycoverage
for each row
update policy.policymonthlypremium
join on policy.policymonthlypremium = coverage.coveragemonthlyrate
```

Comment: post your table structure along with some sample data, your question as it is, tad difficult to understand.

Comment: Updated,Thanks.

Comment: you seems to miss out on giving us crucial information, trigger on which table, which all tables are you modifying via your trigger, what is your trigger code.

Comment: You're right,I clarified it,thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify your trigger code to the below.

1. First fetch monthly coverage rate from the coverage table.
2. Update the policy coverage using the variable.

   ```
   create or replace trigger popmonthlyprem
   after insert on policycoverage
   for each row
   DECLARE
       v_num_cov_mon_rate NUMBER := 0; 
   BEGIN
       SELECT c.COVERAGEMONTHLYRATE
         INTO v_num_cov_mon_rate
         FROM coverage c
        WHERE c.coverageID = :NEW.coverageID;

       UPDATE policy p
          SET p.policymonthlypremium = v_num_cov_mon_rate
        WHERE p.POLICYID = :NEW.POLICYID
   END;
   ```

*NOTE - The trigger will fail, if there is no entry for your policy coverage in the COVERAGE table. You will need to add some exception handling for this.